# In SSRS how can I filter using a StartDate parameter where the format does not include AM or PM

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to use a Start Date parameter in a tablix filter.  The problem is the incoming data is in the following format, 6/06/2013  6:00:00, and does not include AM or PM - which is causing the filter not to work properly.

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you speak about AX:

You can use this function:

```
=Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Reports.DataMethodUtility.ConvertUtcToAxUserTimeZoneForUser(Parameters!AX_CompanyName.Value, Parameters!AX_UserContext.Value, Fields!StartDate, "t", Parameters!AX_RenderingCulture.Value)
```

Fields!StartDate is your DATE field
i never use "t", if it doesn't work try "tt", it will return if your time is "AM" or "PM"